# R- skip empty line in specific column

Tags: r, csv

this is my code that return two columns, one of them has so many empty data.

```
ukb <- read.csv("mydata.csv", header=FALSE, sep=",")
ukb <- read_csv("mydata.csv", col_names = c("EID","Date of alzheimer's disease report.0.0"), col_types = cols(col_double(),col_date()))
ukb
```

and this is the result

```
> ukb
# A tibble: 1,001 x 2
       EID `Date of alzheimer's disease report.0.0`
     <dbl> <date>                                  
 1      NA NA                                      
 2 1000013 NA                                      
 3 1000024 NA                                      
 4 1000036 NA                                      
 5 1000048 NA                                      
 6 1000055 NA                                      
 7 1000067 NA                                      
 8 1000072 NA
```

how can I return results of Date of Alzheimer's disease report.0.0 with data only and ignore the empty lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just filter out the "NAs"...

```
ukb_filtered <- ukb %>%
    filter(!is.na(`Date of alzheimer's disease report.0.0`)
```